# How to make a animated <div> be visible only inside another <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Firstly thank you for accepting me in the group.
I need help with a question about animation with jQuery.
This is an animation which I found on items in the navigation menu of this template, the template monster.

http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/40492.html

Apparently these are two images that move on the canvas and gradually fade at some point.

Studying examples of jQuery I saw that part of the effect is obtained with the use of animation attribute top (css). But unfortunately the element that I animated do not gradually disappears as the example shown in the link.

Please help me understand how I can achieve the same effect using jQuery.

Comment: Place your example inside jsFiddle to get best solution

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to achieve what you want first, and repost your question if you run into trouble.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: i have created a fiddle for you mimicking the animation you specified. http://jsfiddle.net/VU6ur/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply make it as per below.

## CSS

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Six Caps';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Six Caps'), local('SixCaps'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/sixcaps/v5/tMrhQDUBAHnnGuM33-yobPesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff) format('woff');
}
.clear{clear:both;}
.nav{}
.menubox{width:200px;float:left;margin:0px 10px;height:80px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;font-family: 'Six Caps', sans-serif;line-height: 80px;color: #161616;font-size: 80px;color:#000;display:block;cursor:pointer;}
.menubox > span{width:100%;height:80px;display:block;position:absolute;text-align:center;}
.menubox > span.default-txt{top:0px;left:0px;}
.menubox > span.hover-txt{top:80px;left:0px;color:red;}
```

## HTML

```
<div class="nav">
    <a class="menubox">
        <span class="default-txt">menu</span>
        <span class="hover-txt">menu</span>
    </a>
    <a class="menubox">
        <span class="default-txt">menu</span>
        <span class="hover-txt">menu</span>
    </a>
    <a class="menubox">
        <span class="default-txt">menu</span>
        <span class="hover-txt">menu</span>
    </a>
    <a class="menubox">
        <span class="default-txt">menu</span>
        <span class="hover-txt">menu</span>
    </a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

## jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menubox').mouseenter(function(){            
        $(this).children('.default-txt').stop(true,true).animate({top:'-100px'});
        $(this).children('.hover-txt').stop(true,true).animate({top:'0px'});
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).children('.default-txt').stop(true,true).animate({top:'0px'});
        $(this).children('.hover-txt').stop(true,true).animate({top:'100px'});
    });
});
```

## JSFiddle

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6usrz/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was looking for this answer over 12 hours. I hope one day I can return the favor.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/qtdtL/.  Note the that element with the animation for "top" has position: fixed.

```
$("nav").click(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var elTop = el.position().top == 0 ? "-70px" : "0";
    el.animate({top: elTop});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you add

```
div
{
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Safari */
}
```

first property tells what kind of changes that should be animated on change the second one tell how long time it should take and the third one timing, there's also a fourth for giving it a delay if so is desired